# Changing a duplicate

Tags: discussion

So I recently asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30099625/what-is-the-correct-encoding) question and after a few minutes someone commented saying check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/converting-a-string-to-byte-array-without-using-an-encoding-byte-by-byte) question as its a duplicate. Now I originally like that but after further research decided with its accepted answer it is probably not the best 'duplicate'. So I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241405/how-do-you-convert-a-string-to-a-byte-array-in-net) question with the answer by Jon Skeet. His answer as a big discussion and after reading it I realise it is the better of the 2.

So is there anyway I can get a change of duplicate as such so that anyone finding my question is directed to the 'better' answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've re-closed the question as a duplicate of the other question.